# Should be easy (but not for me) css for hover state within class

Tags: css

I have an inline menu of which I want to change the last menu item so that it is a different coloured box with a different coloured text. I've managed to do this  with the below class but I can't seem to work out how to change the hover state no matter what I've tried. How do I script that? Thanks.

```
#navbar a.blogbox {
    background-color: #E4E9E7;
    padding: 3px;
    margin-left: 4px;
    border-left: none;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #c52a45;
}

<div id="navbar">
  <ul>
      <li class="activepage">HOME</li>
      <li><a href="aboutus.html">about us</a></li>
      <li><a href="page1.html">page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="page2.html">page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="page3.html">page 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="page4.html">page 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">contact</a></li>
      <li><a class="blogbox" href="/blog/index.php">Blog</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried for hover?

Comment: Well I thought I tried the below answer, maybe I had a space between blogbox and :hover or maybe the order was wrong like #navbar.blogbox a:hover or something but the below seems to work fine! Seems I wasn't too far off but just far enough to make the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want to happen?

```css
#navbar a.blogbox {
    background-color: #E4E9E7;
    padding: 3px;
    margin-left: 4px;
    border-left: none;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #c52a45;
}
#navbar a.blogbox:hover {
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
  <ul>
      <li class="activepage">HOME</li>
      <li><a href="aboutus.html">about us</a></li>
      <li><a href="page1.html">page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="page2.html">page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="page3.html">page 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="page4.html">page 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">contact</a></li>
      <li><a class="blogbox" href="/blog/index.php">Blog</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, that works. I guess I just had the order wrong. It's been a while since I've had to go into this, thanks.